# Executing SC command with a "/" in the Service name

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to execute the following command in CMD to start / stop services on a remote computer but getting the error.

```
C:\>SC TestPC Query "I/My Service"
```

the problem here is with the service name having a forward slash in it.
How can i solve this?

Comment: What is the error? How do you know the problem is the slash?

Comment: The forward slash is typically used for either a switch character (for command-line options, as in `/d`) or for path separators. Why would you complicate your life by using it as part of your service name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `sc` command itself.  From the [documentation for OpenService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Forward-slash (/) and backslash (\) are invalid service name characters.

The documentation for CreateService contains the same restriction.  Service names simply are not allowed to contain forward or backward slashes.

Comment: Disallowing backslash is a strict necessity since service records are stored in the registry. Forward slash, on the other hand, is allowed in registry key and value names, so apparently that's disallowed on principle.